# Rotation of geometric shape formula in reversed y axis

Tags: math, geometry

I want to do a rotation of a shape about its own center.  the formula I would use on a standard x y axis is:

```
 x' = a + (x-a) cos(theta) - (y-b) sin(theta)
 y' = b + (x-a) sin(theta) + (y-b) cos(theta)
```

However, the axis I am working on has an origin at the top left with x increasing from left to right and y increasing from top to bottom.  How would I change this formula to reflect this?  Do I need to change theta as well?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this formula works both in 'right-hand' and in 'left-hand' coordinate systems (you have left-hand system), and properly rotates coordinates in **given specific system**.
If you need to swap clockwise/counterclockwise directions for proper visual perception, just change theta sign (or signs at Sin)